# Using MaxNLocator for pandas bar plot results in wrong labels

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a pandas dataframe and I want to create a plot of it:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator, FormatStrFormatter, MaxNLocator
df = pd.DataFrame([1, 3, 3, 5, 10, 20, 11, 7, 2, 3, 1], range(-5, 6))
df.plot(kind='barh')
```

Nice, everything works as expected:

[image]

Now I wanted to hide some of the ticks on y axes. Looking at the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html), I thought I can achieve it with:

> MaxNLocator: Finds up to a max number of intervals with ticks at nice
>   locations. MultipleLocator: Ticks and range are a multiple of base;
>   either integer or float.

But both of them plot not what I was expecting to see (the values on the y-axes do not show the correct numbers):

```
ax = df.plot(kind='barh')
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(2))
```

[image]

```
ax = df.plot(kind='barh')
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(3))
```

[image]

---

What do I do wrong?

Comment: You need to set a locator **and** a formatter. Use a `ScalarFormatter` if in doubt. Note that the title is a bit misleading, because the Locator works as expected, you get the correct locations, but not the correct numbers. This is because you are using a `FixedFormatter`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thanks for your feedback. Tried to add `ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter())` but it has not fixed the problem. If you have a better title in mind, I would appreciate you changing it.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was too quick in my reasoning here. The solution is a bit more cumbersome as shown below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Problem

The problem occurs because pandas barplots are categorical. Each bar is positioned at a succesive integer value starting at 0. Only the labels are adjusted to show the actual dataframe index. So here you have a `FixedLocator` with values `0,1,2,3,...` and a `FixedFormatter` with values `-5, -4, -3, ...`. Changing the Locator alone does not change the formatter, hence you get the numbers `-5, -4, -3, ...` but at different locations (one tick is not shown, hence the plot starts at -4 here).

#### A. Pandas solution

In addition to setting the locator you would need to set a formatter, which returns the correct values as function of the location. In the case of a dataframe index with successive integers as used here, this can be done by adding the minimum index to the location using a `FuncFormatter`. For other cases, the function for the `FuncFormatter` may become more complicated.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.ticker import (MultipleLocator, MaxNLocator, 
                                FuncFormatter, ScalarFormatter)

df = pd.DataFrame([1, 3, 3, 5, 10, 20, 11, 7, 2, 3, 1], range(-5, 6))

ax = df.plot(kind='barh')
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(2))

sf = ScalarFormatter()
sf.create_dummy_axis()
sf.set_locs((df.index.max(), df.index.min()))

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(lambda x,p: sf(x+df.index[0])))


plt.show()
```

#### B. Matplotlib solution

Using matplotlib, the solution is potentially easier. Since matplotlib bar plots are numeric in nature, they position the bars at the locations given to the first argument. Here, setting a locator alone is sufficient.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator, MaxNLocator

df = pd.DataFrame([1, 3, 3, 5, 10, 20, 11, 7, 2, 3, 1], range(-5, 6))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.barh(df.index, df.values[:,0])
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(2))

plt.show()
```